# lighttpd/mod_websocket mqtt handshake fail (no subproto)

Tags: websocket, lighttpd, mqtt

I have set up lighttpd with mod_websocket as discussed in Dom Bramley's blog entry (except that I am using a BeagleBone Black with Debian Wheezy instead of an rPi.)

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/B-Fool/entry/setting_up_an_mqtt_websocket_gateway_for_raspberry_pi?lang=en

[During the lighttpd/mod_websocket build process I was asked if I wanted to patch the server and I said yes.]

I have the mosquito MQTT broker running on the same host and publishing on various topics.

When I try to connect to the broker with a browser client via the web socket, I can see that everything works okay in terms of the http upgrade to websocket and forwarding the connection request to mosquitto.  Mosquitto gets the connection request and accepts it.  However, the response that gets back to the browser does not include the Sec-Websocket-Protocol header echoing the subproto specifier mqttv3.1 that was in the original upgrade request.  The client correctly rejects this answer and the connection is shut down.

The javascript error from mqttws31.js:912 is "Sent non-empty Sec-Websocket-Protocol header but no response is received."  With Wireshark, I can see that this is true; the 101 Switching Protocols response has headers Upgrade, Connection, and Sec-Websocket-Accept, but nothing else.

My mod_websocket config file defines host, port, type, and subproto the same as Dom's example, and I can see from various debug statements that the request gets all the way to Mosquitto correctly.

Can anyone suggest how to get the Websocket-Protocol header to be included in the response?  It must work, Dom wrote a blog post describing how he did it!

Comment: If you have too much trouble with mod_websocket, you can always just do your own websockets in node or php or whatever language you are using. https://github.com/esromneb/phpwebsocket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think recent versions of mod_websocket broke/removed subprotocol support, but can't confirm it right now. You could try an earlier version, or use a dedicated websocket to tcp gateway like WSS

https://github.com/stylpen/WSS/

Comment: WSS is a good recommendation. Do use the `tls` branch which has been modified recently to support subprotocols.

Comment: [This issue](https://github.com/stylpen/WSS/issues/14) may be of particular interest.

Comment: @ralight:  You're right about subproto being removed.  The conclusion of a thread on this (https://github.com/nori0428/mod_websocket/issues/28) was "no more handle subproto on mod_websocket ver 2.9. And no need to handle subproto for TCP mode."  I don't know why there's no need for protocol negotiation, it seems pretty fundamental to me! Yes, useful thread.  I'll take a look at using WSS instead.  Doesn't it seem like lighttpd/web_socket is ceding MQTT to others by not supporting subproto?

Comment: It seems like a really stupid decision to remove support, but what do I know! It surely doesn't just cause problems for MQTT.

Comment: I opened an issue on web_socket, [Issue 33](https://github.com/nori0428/mod_websocket/issues/33), perhaps we'll see some background info from that.

Comment: "mod_websocket", not "web_socket".  :-)

Comment: I installed the libboost-all-dev package (and its 80 dependencies), cloned and built websocketpp 0.2.x and WSS tls, wrote a little babble script (because my gps chose this moment to die), started everything running and hey presto! it works!  I was able to connect from Safari to WSS with the [MQTT client page](http://m2m.demos.ibm.com/mqttclient/) and subscribe to live MQTT topic updates from my babbler forwarded by the Mosquitto broker through WSS and the websocket.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The mod_websocket author (Norio Kobota) quickly and effectively resolved this issue for me by making an update to mod_websocket.  The fix is currently in a development branch, and available on github.  Our discussion is part of the thread for [mod_websocket issue 28](https://github.com/nori0428/mod_websocket/issues/28).

Briefly, the use case that I have (pre-written client library and existing TCP backend) is much less flexible than a roll-your-own client and server combination with respect to connect-time protocol negotiation.  However, in my case I don't really need any flexibility or negotiation with the backend, and so mod_websocket can just echo the configuration it has been given without having to dive into the details of the subprotocol.

The updated mod_websocket echoes the subproto entry from its config file during websocket handshake which satisfies the MQTT client library.

So now I have two solutions for adapters between websocket clients and TCP backends!  Thanks all for your help.

Doug Johnson